# How to serialize a diff of two folders optimally in C++

Tags: c++, diff, git-patch

I'm trying to develop a file [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) format for multiple files recursively in folders. Consider a source directory containing patched files and a destination directory containing original files. Write a size minimal `diff` file which expresses the difference between all files in the source and destination directory which can be applied to the original files in order to transform the original files into the patched files.

For this purpose I found the [`dtl`](https://github.com/cubicdaiya/dtl) library. Which algorithm or feature of the library should I use to write a file `diff` to the disk which I can then later read back and apply in order to patch the file?  Any example code for this? I tried writing the result of the `shortest edit script` (`SES`) to the disk but I realized that I needed to specify the character and operation for every single byte. This of course makes the output file bigger than the entire comparison file, making this diff format entirely redundant since storing the entire target file instead would've saved more storage.

As another reference, this is very similar to how version control systems like [`git`](https://git-scm.com) or [`svn`](https://tortoisesvn.net) operate but I don't want to use those since I'm mainly dealing with binary files and the simple requirement of creating and applying patches.

Comment: [GDIFF](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-gdiff-19970901)

Comment: afaik neither git nor svn actually care what is the filetypes, be it binaries or text or whatever

Comment: @eerorika: Thanks, that's a good link
idclev463035818: Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more search, I found the [`HDiffPatch`](https://github.com/sisong/HDiffPatch) project.
It worked fine apparently but it seems to take long on bigger folder comparisons:

```
diff usage: hdiffz [options] oldPath newPath outDiffFile
patch usage: hpatchz [options] oldPath diffFile outNewPath
```

EDIT:
Another good option is [`open-vcdiff`](https://github.com/google/open-vcdiff) but it only supports individual files.

Answer (score 0):

use HDiffPatch: you can run hdiffz with "-s-48" for up speed;
or try "-s-32" , "-s-1k", "-s-128k" ...